# ggplot combine geom_text_repel with facet_zoom

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-text, geom-point

I have the following code sample:

```
x <- c(1,1.2,1.3,1.1,2,2.5,3.6)
y <- c(3,3.1,2.9,3.6,4.5,5.6,6.7)
z <- c('Austria',' Germany', 'Italy', 'France', 'Spain','Portugal', 'Belgium')

dataset <-data.frame(x,y,z)

ggp <- ggplot(dataset, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
 
   geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(label = z),
              size = 2,
              min.segment.length = 0,
              seed = 42,
              box.padding = 0.4,
              arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.007, "npc")),
              nudge_x = .03,
              nudge_y = .03,
              color = "grey60") +

  geom_point(data = dataset,aes(colour=z, size = y/x), alpha=0.6) +

  facet_zoom(x = x < 2, horizontal = FALSE ,zoom.size = 0.3, show.area = FALSE) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")

 ggp
```

I would like to display on the main panel only the names of points that are not in the facet zoom, while in the facet zoom I would like to display only the names of the visible points. Is there a way to do both at the same time?

I would like also to avoid the usage of geom_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `zoom.data` argument from `facet_zoom`:

> zoom.data:     An expression evaluating to a logical vector. If TRUE the
> data only shows in the zoom panels. If FALSE the data only show in the
> context panel. If NA the data will show in all panels.

First, add a `zoom` column to your dataset, and set to `TRUE` if `x` is less than 2 (this will be shown in the zoom panel). Otherwise `zoom` should be set to `FALSE` (this will be shown in context panel).

```
dataset$zoom <- ifelse(dataset$x < 2, TRUE, FALSE)
```

For `facet_zoom` use the `zoom.data` argument and set to the new `zoom` column:

```
facet_zoom(x = x < 2, horizontal = FALSE, zoom.data = zoom, zoom.size = 0.3, show.area = FALSE)
```

Here is the entire code for reproducibility:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggforce)

x <- c(1,1.2,1.3,1.1,2,2.5,3.6)
y <- c(3,3.1,2.9,3.6,4.5,5.6,6.7)
z <- c('Austria',' Germany', 'Italy', 'France', 'Spain','Portugal', 'Belgium')

dataset <-data.frame(x,y,z)

dataset$zoom <- ifelse(dataset$x < 2, TRUE, FALSE)

ggp <- ggplot(dataset, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  
  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(label = z),
                  size = 2,
                  min.segment.length = 0,
                  seed = 42,
                  box.padding = 0.4,
                  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.007, "npc")),
                  nudge_x = .03,
                  nudge_y = .03,
                  color = "grey60") +
  
  geom_point(aes(colour=z, size = y/x), alpha=0.6) +
  
  facet_zoom(x = x < 2, horizontal = FALSE , zoom.data = zoom, zoom.size = 0.3, show.area = FALSE) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")

ggp
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with zoom]